# Getting errror as the server threw exception in QTP

Tags: database, connection, qtp

I am getting error  the server threw exception in QTP

Function file:C:\GPONSanityAutomation\FunctionalLibraries\DatabaseConnection.vbs
Line (42): “con.open “Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=”& strDBDesc &”;User ID=”& strUSERID &”;Password=”& strPassword &”;””

[image]

I am getting this error during database connection
Could you please anyone help me resolve this error.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Are all your variables properly set? Is the driver properly installed? Can you show us your code for a better assistance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install oracle client in your system for database connectivity. If already installed try to create a database checkpoint using the installed driver and check whether you are able to create the checkpoint.